# My iPad get too hot while im testing on it [Running projects on]

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ipad-2

While im testing my new app on my iPad 2 retina , i noticed that my device temperature is getting too high, anyone know why ??

Comment: I dnt think this question belong here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a battery problem.

see this link : [iPad Battery](http://ipod.about.com/od/ipad/a/conserve-ipad-battery-life.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Run your app with Instruments like "Energy Diagnostics Tool" on your device. If your app consumes lots of energy, the battery will drain very fast. Fast battery drain will generate heat. Using Xcode Instruments you can find out is there any problem with your app.